# In R, how to perform an operation on a specific subset of a data.frame?

Tags: r

(I have a feeling I'm gonna feel really dumb after I get an answer but I just could not figure this out.)

I have a data.frame with an empty column on the end. It will mostly be filled with NAs, but I want to populate some rows of it with a value. This column represents a guess at data that is missing from one of the columns in the data.frame.

My initial data.frame looks something like this:

```
Game | Rating | MinPlayers | MaxPlayers | MaxPlayersGuess
---------------------------------------------------------
A    | 6      | 3          | 6          |
B    | 7      | 3          | 7          |
C    | 6.5    | 3          | N/A        |median(df$MaxPlayers[df$MinPlayers ==3,])
D    | 7      | 3          | 6          |
E    | 7      | 3          | 5          |
F    | 9.5    | 2          | 5          |
G    | 6      | 2          | 4          |
H    | 7      | 2          | 4          |
I    | 6.5    | 2          | N/A        |median(df$MaxPlayers[df$MinPlayers ==2,])
J    | 7      | 2          | 2          |
K    | 7      | 2          | 4          |
```

Notice that two of the rows have "N/A" for MaxPlayers. What I am attempting to do is use the information I have to make a guess at What the MaxPlayers might be. If median(MaxPlayers) for 3 players games is 6, MaxPlayerGuess should equal 6 for games with MinPlayers == 3 and MaxPlayers == N/A. (I have attempted to indicate in code what value MaxPlayerGuess should get in the example above.)

The resulting data.frame would look like this:

```
Game | Rating | MinPlayers | MaxPlayers | MaxPlayersGuess
---------------------------------------------------------
A    | 6      | 3          | 6          |
B    | 7      | 3          | 7          |
C    | 6.5    | 3          | N/A        |6
D    | 7      | 3          | 6          |
E    | 7      | 3          | 5          |
F    | 9.5    | 2          | 5          |
G    | 6      | 2          | 4          |
H    | 7      | 2          | 4          |
I    | 6.5    | 2          | N/A        |4
J    | 7      | 2          | 2          |
K    | 7      | 2          | 4          |
```

To share the results of one attempt:

```
gld$MaxPlayersGuess <- ifelse(is.na(gld$MaxPlayers), median(gld$MaxPlayers[gld$MinPlayers,]), NA)


Error in gld$MaxPlayers[gld$MinPlayers, ] : 
incorrect number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating relative to posted example.

Here's my tip of the day, sometimes it's easier to compute what you want and then grab it when you need rather than use all of these logical contigencies. You're trying to come up with a way to compute it all at once and that's making it confusing, break it into steps. You need to know the median value of "MaxPlayer" for each possible group of "MinPlayer". Then you want to use that value when MaxPlayer is missing. So here's a simple way to do that.

```
#generate fake data 
MinPlayer <- rep(3:2, each = 4)
MaxPlayer <- rep(2:5, each = 2, times = 2)

df <- data.frame(MinPlayer, MaxPlayer)

#replace some values of MaxPlayer with NA
df$MaxPlayer <- ifelse(df$MaxPlayer == 3, NA, df$MaxPlayer)

####STARTING DATA
# > df
# MinPlayer MaxPlayer
# 1          3         2
# 2          3         2
# 3          3        NA
# 4          3        NA
# 5          2         4
# 6          2         4
# 7          2         5
# 8          2         5
# 9          3         2
# 10         3         2
# 11         3        NA
# 12         3        NA
# 13         2         4
# 14         2         4
# 15         2         5
# 16         2         5

####STEP 1
#find the median of MaxPlayer for each group of MinPlayer (e.g., when MinPlayer == 1, 2 or whatever)
#just add a column to the data frame that has the right median value for each subset of MinPlayer in it and grab that value to use later. 
library(plyr) #plyr is a great way to compute things across data subsets
df <- ddply(df, c("MinPlayer"), transform, 
            median.minp = median(MaxPlayer, na.rm = TRUE)) #ignore NAs in the median

####STEP 2
#anytime that MaxPlayer == NA, grab the median value to replace the NA, otherwise keep the MaxPlayer value
df$MaxPlayer <- ifelse(is.na(df$MaxPlayer), df$median.minp, df$MaxPlayer)

####STEP 3
#you had to compute an extra column you don't really want, so drop it now that you're done with it
df <- df[ , !(names(df) %in% "median.minp")]

####RESULT
# > df
# MinPlayer MaxPlayer
# 1          2         4
# 2          2         4
# 3          2         5
# 4          2         5
# 5          2         4
# 6          2         4
# 7          2         5
# 8          2         5
# 9          3         2
# 10         3         2
# 11         3         2
# 12         3         2
# 13         3         2
# 14         3         2
# 15         3         2
# 16         3         2
```

---

Old answer below here....

Please post a reproducible example!!

```
#fake data 
this <- rep(1:2, each = 1, times = 2)
that <- rep(3:2, each = 1, times = 2)

df <- data.frame(this, that)
```

If you're just asking about basic indexing.... E.g., find values where something meets a condition, this will return the row indexes of values matching the condition (look up ?which):

```
> which(df$this < df$that)
[1] 1 3
```

This will return the VALUE of things matching your condition not the row index - you just use the row index returned by "which" to find the corresponding value in the correct column of your data frame (here "this")

```
> df[which(df$this < df$that), "this"]
[1] 1 1
```

If you want to apply some calculation when "this" is "less" than that and add a new column to your data frame, just use "ifelse". If else creates a logical vector where stuff matches your condition and then does stuff to things matching your condition (e.g., where your logical test == TRUE).

```
#if "this" is < "that", multiply by 2 
df$result <- ifelse(df$this < df$that, df$this * 2, NA)

> df
this that result
1    1    3      2
2    2    2     NA
3    1    3      2
4    2    2     NA
```

Without an reproducible example, no more can be provided.

Comment: Apologies, because I don't know how to even begin coding the procedure I do not know how to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer. By trying out some of your suggestions I was able to see the problem better and figure out how to post an example.

Comment: @Zelbinian, so generally you'd mark griffmer's as an answer

Comment: @Chris But I still don't know how to solve the problem... All I learned was how to state it more precisely. The key difference is the value the calculation is based in depends on the MinPlayers value in the same row that's currently being executed and I don't know how to access that.

Comment: @Zelbinian, is.na() is the test that you want to determine where to impute your max player guess. so: max_play_idx <- which(is.na(df$max_players) == TRUE) gets you index of where you want to calculate. Then I think you slip into a different kind of problem. Inferring the probable max_players is related to known ratings, min_players, and and max_players, column-wise. Essentially your question changes here. But dput(), help('dput') will help you get out of a lot of typing and formatting, as you already have a data.table. Stating it more precisely is half the battle. And may not be based on minPl

Comment: @Chris - I don't think the `== TRUE` part is necessary. `is.na()` already creates a logical vector. I haven't had any trouble with that part. (Apologies if that wasn't clear.) The part I'm having trouble with is the row-wise calculation. I suppose I should just try a for loop.

Comment: @Zelbinian min_2_idx <- which( is.na() == TRUE & minplayer ==2),  min3idx <- which(is.na == TRUE & minplayer == 3). df$MaxPlayerGuess[min3idx] <- median(df$MaxPlayers[df$MinPlayers ==3,]), perhaps. Anyway, the row indexing as you describe is to ==2 or == 3 and using griffmer's above, this should get you in the right direction as you'll need a different index for each.

Comment: @Zelbinian - Did this answer work for you? And the below couple of answers? If so you, you should mark what worked as accepted or provide some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you already have everything you need in @griffmer's answer. But a less elegant but maybe more intuitive way could be a loop:

```
## Your data:
df <- data.frame(
        Game = LETTERS[1:11],
        Rating = c(6,7,6.5,7,7,9.5,6,7,6.5,7,7),
        MinPlayers = c(rep(3,5), rep(2,6)),
        MaxPlayers = c(6,7,NA,6,5,5,4,4,NA,2,4)     
)

## Loop over rows:
df$MaxPlayersGuess <- vapply(1:nrow(df), function(ii){
            if (is.na(df$MaxPlayers[ii])){
                median(df$MaxPlayers[df$MinPlayers == df$MinPlayers[ii]],
                        na.rm = TRUE)               
            } else {
                df$MaxPlayers[ii]
            }           
        }, numeric(1))
```

which gives you

```
df
#    Game Rating MinPlayers MaxPlayers MaxPlayersGuess
# 1     A    6.0          3          6               6
# 2     B    7.0          3          7               7
# 3     C    6.5          3         NA               6
# 4     D    7.0          3          6               6
# 5     E    7.0          3          5               5
# 6     F    9.5          2          5               5
# 7     G    6.0          2          4               4
# 8     H    7.0          2          4               4
# 9     I    6.5          2         NA               4
# 10    J    7.0          2          2               2
# 11    K    7.0          2          4               4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `dplyr` , you can try:

input:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Game = LETTERS[1:11],
  Rating = c(6,7,6.5,7,7,9.5,6,7,6.5,7,7),
  MinPlayers = c(rep(3,5), rep(2,6)),
  MaxPlayers = c(6,7,NA,6,5,5,4,4,NA,2,4)     
)
```

process:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(MinPlayers) %>%
  mutate(MaxPlayers = if_else(is.na(MaxPlayers), median(MaxPlayers, na.rm=TRUE), MaxPlayers))
```

this groups the data basis `MinPlayers` and then assigns median value of `MaxPlayers` to the rows with missing data.

output:

```
Source: local data frame [11 x 4]
Groups: MinPlayers [2]

     Game Rating MinPlayers MaxPlayers
   <fctr>  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1       A    6.0          3          6
2       B    7.0          3          7
3       C    6.5          3          6
4       D    7.0          3          6
5       E    7.0          3          5
6       F    9.5          2          5
7       G    6.0          2          4
8       H    7.0          2          4
9       I    6.5          2          4
10      J    7.0          2          2
11      K    7.0          2          4
```